# GStreamer Picture in Picture rtmp to rtmp

Tags: h.264, gstreamer, rtmp

How to mix two rtmp streams in gstreamer?

Src: nginx-rtmp cams - h.264/speex 
Sink: nginx-rtmp

GStreamer 0.10 or 1.0

```
 ----------        -------
| rtmp src |----->|       |
 ----------       |       |       ---------- 
                  | video |----->| rtmp sink|
 ----------       | mixer |       ----------  
| rtmp src |----->|       |
 ----------       |       |
                   -------
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with videomixer, videoscale and videobox.

This answer should give you some ideas: [Can I use the Gstreamer API to merge 2 videos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159642/can-i-use-the-gstreamer-api-to-merge-2-videos)

Answer (score 2):

I manually publish two stream on Red5 server (Santosh, Amit), using following pipeline I can able to mix two stream and publish another stream on Red5 (Test).

```
GST_DEBUG=videomixer:6 gst-launch-1.0 videomixer sink_1::xpos=10\ sink_1::ypos=0 sink_2::xpos=10 sink_1::ypos=220 sink_3::xpos=50 \sink_1::ypos=120  name=mix ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, height=500, \width=1000 ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=2000 ! flvmux ! rtmpsink \location='rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx/oflaDemo/Test live=1'  rtmpsrc name=src1 \location='rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx/oflaDemo/Amit live=1' ! decodebin ! \mix.sink_1 rtmpsrc name=src2 \location='rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx/oflaDemo/Santosh live=1' ! decodebin !\ mix.sink_2
```